# Ruby on Rails Filters Applied to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, filter

I'm looking to create an application that can add 'filters' to a view after it has been rendered. For example, if my view renders to:

```
"<html><body>demo</body></html>"
```

I want to capitalize all letters so it looks like:

```
"<HTML><BODY>DEMO</BODY></HTML>"
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple version (in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`):

```
after_filter do |c|
  c.response.body = c.response.body.upcase
end
```

However, this is probably bad since it will literally uppercase everything. You probably want to restrict it to only HTML responses and, even then, you'll want to make sure it doesn't create invalid markup (for example, it should ignore `<script>` tags and the like).

Comment: The upper case was just an example. Thanks! Exactly what I needed!